# Visual Studio 2015 unexpectedly breaking on handled exceptions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, exception, break

An image being worth a lot of words, how is the following possible:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 breaking while it should not]

As can be seen, Visual Studio 2015 (latest version) breaks while `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` under `Exception Settings` is unchecked, `Enable Just My Code` under `Tools > Options > Debugging` is checked, and the exception is clearly handled (within a try/catch block).

The line failing and causing the break is a call to an external API (which is somewhat buggy, hence the try/catch block).

Am I missing something that would justify the break or is this a bug? I thought [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549030/visual-studio-2015-break-on-unhandled-exceptions-not-working) would provide some insight but it unfortunately does not help here (the exception is handled so we should not need to enable the additional `Continue When Unhandled in User Code` option.

Comment: I believe it was answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4759831/2529330

Comment: It is indeed! Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special case for this exception, which I am guessing applies here. From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **AccessViolationException and try/catch blocks**
>
> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, AccessViolationException exceptions thrown by the common language runtime are not handled by the catch statement in a structured exception handler if the exception occurs outside of the memory reserved by the common language runtime. To handle such an AccessViolationException exception, you should apply the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute attribute to the method in which the exception is thrown. This change does not affect AccessViolationException exceptions thrown by user code, which can continue to be caught by a catch statement. For code written for previous versions of the .NET Framework that you want to recompile and run without modification on the .NET Framework 4, you can add the  element to your app's configuration file. Note that you can also receive notification of the exceptions if you have defined a handler for the AppDomain.FirstChanceException or AppDomain.UnhandledException event.

As the docs say, the solution is to add the [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to the `Start()` method. If not possible (e.g., this is supplied via a library), I'm guessing you can add a method that wraps the call and add the attribute to that wrapping method.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the answer in the following link
[How to handle AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception/4759831#4759831)

For many reasons, in .NET 4.0 the runtime handles some exceptions as Windows Structured Error Handling (SEH) errors as indicators for Corrupted State, and those can not be caught as regular exceptions.

Enjoy