# RasException occured dueto password error

Tags: c#

I  have made an PPP dialer using C# & DOTRAS. When I enter wrong username and password, I get this exception error.

*RasExecption occured:
The remote connection was denied because the user name and password combination you provided is not recognized, or the selected authentication protocol is not permitted on the remote access server.*

[RASEXCEPTION dueto incorrect user/pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KGy4.png)

I have tried to catch this error and make it appear in text box, but failed.

```
var conns = RasConnection.GetActiveConnections();
var conn = conns.FirstOrDefault(o => o.EntryName == Globals.PPPNAME);
if (conn != null)
{
    this.StatusTextBox.AppendText(string.Format("{0}\r\n\r\n", "Dialer already connected !"));
}
else
    try
    {
        this.rasDialer1.DialAsync();

    }

    catch(RasException ex)
    {

    this.StatusTextBox.AppendText("\r\n" + ex.Message + "USERNAME PASSWORD IS INVALID...");
    }
```

Comment: Did you check your exception settings? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549030/visual-studio-2015-break-on-unhandled-exceptions-not-working

Comment: I am using VS2012 on Windows 7 64bit. I tried to change RasExeception to Exception as well but no use.,